# modify an array list

Tags: java, arrays, list

i've been struggling modify an array list that is passed into a method.  i can only modify that array list without creating any new array list in that method.

here is the problem:

Write a method `stutter` that takes an `ArrayList` of `Strings` and an `integer` `k` as parameters and that replaces every string with k copies of that string. For example, if the list stores the values `["how", "are", "you?"]` before the method is called and k is 4, it should store the values `["how", "how", "how", "how", "are", "are", "are", "are", "you?", "you?", "you?", "you?"]` after the method finishes executing. If k is 0 or negative, the list should be empty after the call.

One way to do it with creating new array list:

```
public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> list, int k) {
     ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
     String s = "";
     if(k > 0) {
         for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
             s = list.get(i);
             for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                a.add(s);
             }
         }
     } 
}
```

What is one way to modify that `ArrayList<String> list` only without creating new array list? thanks

Comment: Um, call `list.add(...)`?

Comment: Use `list` instead of `a` inside your method, although note that this is generally not a good idea as it could cause issues later, much better to return a new one.

Comment: Remember that you would want to change your for loop to `j < k - 1` as it already contains one instance of `s`. Is order important?

Comment: yeah i tried that and it gave me an indefinite loop

Comment: An indefinite loop? It definitely looks like a loop to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void addItem(List<String> list, int k){
    int size = list.size() * k;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i=i+k){
        String s = list.get(i);
        for (int j=0; j<k-1; j++){
            list.add(i+j, s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the size of the `ArrayList` to a variable before you do the iteration.

```
int size = list.size();
for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
        list.add(list.get(j));
    }
}
```

However, for your example, the list will become `["how","are","your","how","are","your","how","are","your","how","are","your"]`.
If you want the same value to be together:

```
int size = list.size();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    String s = list.get(i*k);
    for(int j=0;j<k-1;j++){
        list.add(i*k+j, s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void addItem(List<String> list, int k) {

    int size = list.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size * (k - 1); i++) {
        list.add("");
    }

    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int m = k - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
            list.set(k * i + m, list.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

This approach will maintain two pointers, filling up the list backward, without any shifting involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, int k) {
    if (k > 0) {
    int index = 0;
    k = k - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i = i + (k + 1)) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            arrayList.add(index, arrayList.get(i));
        }
        index = index + (k + 1);
    }
}
    else
    arrayList.clear(); 
}
```

input: `[how, are, you?], k=4`

output: `[how, how, how, how, are, are, are, are, you?, you?, you?, you?]`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> list, int k) {
    if (k <= 0) {
        list.clear();
    }
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int r = 1; r < k; r++) {
            list.add(i + 1, list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would explanation be best if you could provide some for why it does so.

Comment: First, you want to start with the base case, namely, when k is less than or equal to zero. As stated in the problem, if this happens, you want to return an empty list. By starting at the end of the list you never lose your spot in the list.  add k(exclusive) strings to the list, once finished, you shift over to the next word until you're at the first index. I found an O(N) way of doing this too, if anyone is interested in seeing it.